# Is this proof of convergence right?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I was curious to analyze the convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{(2+\frac{1}{n})}}$$ Because I would be able to evaluate it via integral $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{x}}} \ dx$$
$$= \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)^\frac{1}{x} \ dx $$ if I replace by $u=\frac{1}{x}$ I get
$$\int_{0}^{1} u^u \ du$$
Which means that the integral has a finite value and hence the series converges.
But I am not sure if I failed somewhere during this reasoning and would like to know if there is any error.

Comment: You could also do comparison to $\sum n^{-2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, it is great way to prove it actually.

I will just organize it slightly:

We know: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{(2+\frac{1}{n})}} \le \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}*\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{n}}} dx$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{(2+\frac{1}{n})}} \le \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}*(\frac{1}{x})^\frac{1}{n} dx $$
Using the substitution $u=\frac{1}{x}$ yields:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{(2+\frac{1}{n})}} \le \int_{0}^{1}u^u du$$

And since $$ \int_{0}^{1}u^u du = C $$ where $C$ is a finite constant.

Therefore, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2{(2+\frac{1}{n})}} \le C  $$
Meaning, the sum has a value less than or equal to C $\implies$ Converges.

Also, if this helps, we can simplify the integral to another sum: $$\int_{0}^{1}u^udu$$ as follows:
$$\int_{0}^{1}u^u du = \int_{0}^{1}e^{u\ln(u)} du $$

Recall, $$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$ valid for all $z$.
$$\implies \int_{0}^{1}e^{u\ln(u)} du = \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(u\ln(u))^n}{n!}du $$
$$\implies \int_{0}^{1}e^{u\ln(u)} du =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} \int_{0}^{1}u^n*(\ln(u))^n du \space\space\space\space (*)$$

Let $$ J = \int_{0}^{1}u^n*(\ln(u))^n du $$
Make the change of variables $u=-\ln(x)$ to get:
$$J = \lim_{\alpha-->\infty} (-1)^n\int_{0}^{\alpha}e^{-(n+1)u}u^n du$$

Let $t=(n+1)u$

Hence, $$J = (-1)^n \lim_{\alpha-->\infty} \int_{0}^{\alpha} \frac{t^n*e^{-t}}{(n+1)^{(n+1)}} dt \iff J = \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \lim_{\alpha-->\infty} \int_{0}^{\alpha} t^n*e^{-t} dt $$

The RHS looks similar to $\Gamma(z)=\lim_{\alpha -->\infty} \int_{0}^{\alpha}e^{-t}t^{z-1} dt$

So, $$J = \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \Gamma(n+1) = \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}*n! $$

Substituting in (*) yields:
$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{u\ln(u)} du = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^n} $$
Which is our original integral. It is known that this alternating series converges to ~0.7834. The proof however, I do not know of.

(Note I got this integral simplification idea from Dr. Peyam on YouTube.)

Comment: The OP uses the Integral test which requires the function to be monotone decreasing. See the other answer.

Comment: @bob, Oh yes, I forgot to use it at the start, but it came out to be monotone decreasing either way.

Comment: That was brilliant, I really appreciate your contribution, sir.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing something: you need to show that your integrand $\frac{1}{x^{2 + 1/x}}$ is monotone decreasing for sufficiently large $x$. This is a requirement of the integral test.

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^{2 + 1/x}}$. Then, using logarithmic differentiation,
\begin{align*}
\log f(x) &= -\left(2 + \frac{1}{x}\right)\log x \\
f'(x) &= f(x) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\log x - \frac{2}{x} - \frac{2}{x^2}\right) \\
&= \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \cdot (\log x - 2x - 2).
\end{align*}
For large $x$, the $-2x - 2$ will dominate the logarithm, and $\frac{f(x)}{x^2} > 0$ for any $x$, so for large $x$, $f'(x) \le 0$, and so the integrand is monotone decreasing. Thus, the integral test holds, and your (augmented) solution shows convergence.

Comment: I thought this condition was valid to just establish a relation between a series and an integral (even if the integral yields infinity, for example). But, if an integral, in an interval of positive terms (from a point to infinity), shares the same expression of a series and yields a finit value, doesn't it automatically mean that the function is decreasing and tending to zero at it's "end". Otherwise, it would diverge, would not?

Comment: @excitedGoose No, the monotonicity requirement is necessary. Remember, you are essentially just sampling a whole continuous function at integer points. Without monotonicity, you could have your function drop to $0$ at integer points, but have infinite area under the function. Or, you could create sharp, large peaks at integer points, but still have a finite area. Monotonicity is necessary for the usual argument, involving forming the series as right/left Riemann sums, and either fitting this in the region under the graph, or vice-versa.

Comment: As a concrete example, consider $f(x) = \inf_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} |x - n|$. This is a continuous (indeed, non-expansive) function that produces essentially a sawtooth wave; $0$ at integer points, $1/2$ at the midpoints of successive integers, and straight lines connecting them. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 0 = 0$, but $\int_0^n f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{n}{4} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.